# zod dynamic props based on state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

I have a object that can have either one or the other props based on a state in react called **state**.
I'm trying to add this to zod schema to throw error if either are empty or undefined based on the state.

**Data.ts**

```
const dataFields: DataFields = (data, state) => {

  const { name, breed, height, sessionId } = data;

  try {
    const summary = {
      sessionId,
      ...(state === "human" && { name }),
      ...(state === "animal" && { breed }),
      height: height,
    };

    const validatedSummary = validateSummary(summary, state);
    return summary;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**Zod validator**

```
const summarySchema = z.object({
  sessionId: z.string(),
  name: z
    .string()
    .refine((data, state: string) => state=== "human" && typeof data.name === "string", {
      message: "name must be defined",
    }),
  breed: z
    .string()
    .refine((data, state: string) => state === "animal" && typeof data.breed === "string", {
      message: "breed must be defined",
    }),
});

type ValidatePayload = z.infer<typeof summarySchema>;

export const validateSummary = (summaryData: ValidatePayload, state: string) => {
  try {
    return summarySchema.parse(summaryData, state);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof ZodError) {
      console.error("Validation failed:", error.errors);
    } else {
      console.error("Unexpected error:", error);
    }
  }
};
```

I'm getting typescript error on summarySchema.parse(**summaryData**, **state**);

> Type 'string' has no properties in common with type
> 'Partial'.ts(2559) (parameter) state: string

Then when I try to pass type I get more overload typescript errors.

> Overload 1 of 2, '(check: (arg: string) => arg is any, message?:
> string | Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">> | ((arg: string) =>
> Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">>) | undefined): ZodEffects<...>',
> gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(data: any, state: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg: string) => arg is any'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.   Overload 2 of 2, '(check: (arg: string) => unknown,
> message?: string | Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">> | ((arg:
> string) => Partial<Omit<ZodCustomIssue, "code">>) | undefined):
> ZodEffects<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(data: any, state: any) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(arg: string) => unknown'.
> Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.

Is there a cleaner and simpler way of doing this  ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you could try this. It uses inheritance, although this is not necessary. The key part is the use of `zod` `discriminatedUnion` base on the property `state`:

```js
const baseSchema = z.object({
  height: z.string(),
  sessionId: z.string(),
});

const nameSchema = baseSchema.extend({
  state: z.literal('human'),
  name: z.string().refine((val) => val.length > 0, {
    message: 'name must be defined',
  }),
});
const breedSchema = baseSchema.extend({
  state: z.literal('animal'),
  breed: z.string().refine((val) => val.length > 0, {
    message: 'breed must be defined',
  }),
});

const theSchema = z.discriminatedUnion('state', [nameSchema, breedSchema]);
```

You can try [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3cakum?file=index.ts).